# Is it to possible to have parallel access of Pi's camera to take stills, when it is streaming through FFMpEG video streaming?

Tags: camera, streaming-video, raspicam

Is it to possible to have parallel access of Pi's camera to take stills, when it is streaming through FFMpEG video streaming ?, if not, then how both ( still and streaming) can be processed at the same time, pl reply.

Answer (score 2):

Only one process can access the camera module at a given time, so you couldn't have, say, `raspivid` feeding data to ffmpeg and simultaneously use `raspistill` to capture images. That said, the underlying firmware does support the concept of a "splitter" component which can be used to accomplish something similar (e.g. by connecting one port of the splitter to a video encoder, and another to an image encoder).

An example of using this from python is given in [this recipe](http://picamera.readthedocs.org/en/release-1.10/recipes2.html#capturing-images-whilst-recording).

Answer (score 0):

This can be possible if you use opencv..
Video grab funtion might help.. you can get furthur details on this link..  http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-grab